# Multithreading with vtkSMPTools

Tags: python, vtk

I want to use `vtkSMPTools` to run my backend parallel (Python). Sample code is as follows:

```
import vtk

# Create an instance of vtkSMPTools
smpTools = vtk.vtkSMPTools()

# Use the For method to iterate over a range of indices in parallel
def func(i):
    # Code to execute in parallel goes here
    print(i)

smpTools.For(0, 100, func)
```

However, I am getting an error as follows:
`vtkmodules.vtkCommonCore.vtkSMPTools' object has no attribute 'For'`.

I have checked the vtk documentation and can see `For` method is defined for vtkSMPTools.

I am unable to figure out what is the issue. Please help me with this.

I am able to import `vtk.vtkSMPTools()`. However, error comes when I am trying to use the `For` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear vtkSMPTools are not expected to work from python code, as templated methods (like the `For` method in the c++ code) are not wrappable (see this [doc](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html//md__builds_gitlab_kitware_sciviz_ci_Documentation_Doxygen_PythonWrappers.html#wrappable) )